# Is jittable's increase in size correlated with memory leak on android?

Tags: java, android, performance, memory-leaks

I keep seeing this:

```
Jit: Resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024 
(...)
Jit: Resizing JitTable from 1024 to 2048 
(...)
Jit: Resizing JitTable from 2048 to 4096
```

Does this mean that I am leaking memory somewhere or is it normal? Also, could you explain what it means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not leaking memory, this is normal. Jit is the just in time compiler of dalvik's vm (the heart of android).

What you see int the log is by the function dvmJitResizeJitTable which Resizes the JitTable I don't know exactly what JitTable is but take look at its source [here](https://github.com/android/platform_dalvik/blob/master/vm/interp/Jit.cpp) at line 1322 and in the comments of this function.

Hope this helps...